# Docker compose with secrets from cloud provider

Tags: docker, docker-compose, azure-keyvault

I am using docker-compose to set up a webserver, this needs to get some passwords that i want to store securely in azure keyvault. The webserver is also hosted in a VM living in Azure in the same Virtual Network as the keyvault store.

Does anyone know what would be the proper way to fetch those secrets from keyvault when using `docker compose up -d`?

The Dockercompose would be something like:

```yaml
version: '2'
services:

  backend:
    image: myimage:0.1
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 2300:2300
    environment:
      - PGSQL_HOST=mydns.postgres.database.azure.com
      - PGSQL_PORT=5432
      - PGSQL_USERNAME=postgres@mypostgres
      - PGSQL_PSWD=<here secret password from keyvault>
```

is there any smart and clean solution to directly insert the secrets here? Or i have to get them using `az keyvault` in the terminal of the VM and then set them up as ENV variables or something similar?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Create an access policy in `Key Vault` for the managed identity you created.

And enable the "Get" secret permission on this policy.

[image]

- Azure CLI to fetch the secrets from the `key vault`.

```
az keyvault secret show --name "mysecret4411" --vault-name "myvault4411"
```

[image]

> is there any smart and clean solution to directly insert the secrets here? Or i have to get them using `az keyvault` in the terminal of the VM and then set them up as ENV variables or something similar?

Yes, by using Azure Container Apps service. Declare the secrets at the application level and then reference them in environment variables when you create a new revision in your container app.

[image]

- Referring the secrets in `docker-compose file` using Azure Container Apps.

```
version: '2'
services:

  backend:
    image: myimage:0.1
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 2300:2300
    environment:
      - PGSQL_HOST=mydns.postgres.database.azure.com
      - PGSQL_PORT=5432
      - PGSQL_USERNAME=postgres@mypostgres
      - PGSQL_PSWD=@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://myvault.vault.azure.net/secrets/mysecret/)
```

For more information refer to [Manage secrets in Azure Container Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/manage-secrets?tabs=azure-portal) and [Store a multiline secret in Azure Key Vault.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/multiline-secrets)